# Typescript merge types

Tags: typescript

I have type `A` and type `B`

```
type A = {
    kind: "A",
    value: string,
    value2: string,
    value3: string,
};

type B = { kind: "B" } & A ;
```

I want to type `B` has all the properties of type `A` but with different `kind` value

But when I write this

```
const temp: B = {
    kind: "B",
    value: "X",
    value2: "X2",
    value3: "X3",
};
```

I get this error

> TS2322 type `string` is not assignable to type `never`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because kind can't be of type "A" and "B" at the same type.

Ways to fix:

**1. Generics:**

```
type WithKind<T extends string> = {
    kind: T,
    value: string,
    value2: string,
    value3: string,
}

type A = WithKind<"A">;

type B = WithKind<"B">;
```

**2. Omit:**

```
type B = Omit<A, "kind"> & { kind: "B" } ;
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem stems from the fact that

```
"A" & "B" === never
```

If you want to override a fixed string value with a new one, you can [Omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittk) it first.

```
type B = { kind: "B" } & Omit<A, "kind">;
```